# show that each of three successive integers $8n^2$,$8n^2+1$, $8n^2+2$ can be written as a sum of two squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a triangular number, show that each of three successive integers $8n^2$,$8n^2+1$, $8n^2+2$ can be written as a sum of two squares.

$$8n^2 = (2n)^2+(2n)^2$$
and for $$8n^2+2 = 4n^2 + 4n^2+1+1-4n+4n= (4n^2 +4n +1)+(4n^2 +4n -1)= (2n+1)^2+(2n-1)^2$$

For $8n^2+1$ i was trying to do the same maneuver  but it is not working.

Comment: You need to use that $n$ is a triangular number somewhere.

Comment: your middle line should be $8 n^2 + 2,$ also you put a minus sign on one of the $1$'s rather than one of the $4n$'s

Comment: i do not understand what you are saying

Comment: Will is saying (in the bit about the minus sign) that it should be $4n^2-4n+1,$ rather than $4n^2+4n-1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have $$8n^2+2=(2n+1)^2+(2n-1)^2,$$ instead.

As for showing that $8n^2+1$ is the sum of two squares, be aware that you haven't yet used the fact that $n$ is a triangular number! In particular, there is a nonnegative integer $k$ such that $$n=\frac12k(k+1).$$ Try putting that into the expression $8n^2+1,$ and see what you can do.

Comment: Yeah i remember a friend of mine mention this idea but i could not work it out

Comment: Did you try to find all the solutions for some small values of $k$? If so, you should notice a pattern that works more generally. If not, what did you try?